# How to Iterate over data from one Oracle Query in another Query.

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I'm new to world of PL/SQL and Oracle SQL queries.

What I'm trying to achieve?
Get all the boxes that are shipped on last 100th day from today (sysdate - 100) with label "600". Of these boxes, I need to segregate the boxes that have an updated label of "50" and "51".

Logic:
1. Get all the boxes  shipped on last 100th with label "600". Also, get the count of how many were shipped in last 100 days with label "600". (Eg, today is 09/06, get all boxes that are shipped on 05/29 ) 
2.  Get the count of all the boxes that have an updated label. E.G, On 06/01 one of the boxes moved from "600" -> "50", I would need to consider this box.

I'm trying to write a PL/SQL for this use case and this is so far I have reached.

```
    VARIABLE box_id CHAR(50);

    BEGIN
       FOR box_id IN (SELECT
       box_id, box_lable
       FROM
       my.box_table
       WHERE box_lable = '600'
       AND trunc(boxed_date) = trunc(SYSDATE - 100)
       ) LOOP

       select count(*), box_lable
       from my.shipping_info si
       where  box_id = si.box_id
       and box_lable in ( '51', '50')
       group by box_lable

--COde to print the  count of box_label = 600; count of box_label = 51; count of box_label = 50 .  

  END LOOP;
END;
```

The above code is throwing an error in SQL Developer. I'm running this on Oracle 11g and Oracle 12c. 
I'm flexible to use any approach (not necessarily PL/SQL) as long the solution works for Oracle.

Can you please suggest me the changes I need to make to run this code snippet?

Comment: So: You have two tables, `box_table` and `shipping_info`? Is `box_id` unique (perhaps primary key) in one table and foreign key in the other? What is an "updated" label - just any label (for that `box_id`) that can be found in the `shipping_info` table? This is all information that you should provide in your post - in addition to the code, as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plain SQL with a subquery instead of PL/SQL loop:

```
select box_lable, count(*)
from my.shipping_info si
where  box_id IN (
       SELECT box_id
       FROM my.box_table
       WHERE box_lable = '600'
       AND trunc(boxed_date) = trunc(SYSDATE - 100)
  )
  and box_lable in ( '51', '50')
group by box_lable
```

---

Also consider rewriting this condition:

```
AND trunc(boxed_date) = trunc(SYSDATE - 100)
```

into this one:

```
AND boxed_date >= trunc(SYSDATE - 100) 
AND boxed_date < trunc(SYSDATE - 99 )
```

This may seem verbose, but helps the optimizes to choose better execution plan, especially allows for using an index on `boxed_date` if it exists (the function `trunc(boxed_date)` prevents the optiomizer from using that index).

Comment: Thank you ! I guess you simplified my problem statement.. i guess this should work